# Ignoring status codes in New Relic with custom agent

Tags: azure, newrelic, nancy

I'm using the custom agent setup for Nancy as outlined [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Nancy-and-New-Relic) for a web site hosted in Azure. Normally, everything works fine, but my service returns some 4xx errors that I don't want reported in New Relic. Unfortunately, my changes to the newrelic.config file don't appear to be getting picked up.

My errorCollector section looks fairly standard:

```
<errorCollector enabled="true">
  <ignoreErrors>
    <exception>System.IO.FileNotFoundException</exception>
    <exception>System.Threading.ThreadAbortException</exception>
  </ignoreErrors>
  <ignoreStatusCodes>
    <code>400</code>
    <code>401</code>
    <code>403</code>
    <code>404</code>
    <code>405</code>
    <code>409</code>
  </ignoreStatusCodes>
</errorCollector>
```

but the site still says only 401 and 404 (the defaults) are ignored.

It looks like this was a bug in New Relic 2.x and was [fixed in 3.0](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/agent-release-notes/net-release-notes/net-agent-30790), but I just upgraded to 3.4.

I can move the configuration to New Relic itself, but I like having the history available in git.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this really only applies to the service and not on the New Relic (even though you can configure it from their site). To make it work, I had to figure out what status code I would return and then include that in my New Relic report.

Comment: I know this is old, but can you explain this a little more. I am currently running into the same issue.

Comment: If the New Relic agent intercepts the exception, it'll record an error before  my code to convert the exception to a status code fires, so ignoring status codes didn't help. I eventually found that I could explicitly exclude exceptions from being reported by the New Relic agent, but it's still clumsy. You can see an example [in their docs](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/installation-configuration/net-agent-configuration#error_collector).

Comment: Odd, the way I was able to resolve this was by using the full status codes ie 400.0 and 401.0. I know the docs say that it supports both but in my case, it didn't work.